# Unity DI Inject DbContext with PerRequestLifetimeManager

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unity-container

I have the following code that initialize instances with Unity:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<DbContext, VotingSystemContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());    
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromAssemblies(
        Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IUserService)),
        Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserService))),
    WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
    WithName.Default, WithLifetime.PerResolve);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

I use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` so I followed the suggestion on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.perrequestlifetimemanager%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx) and added new line at the end of the code above:

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

But after I placed it. When the page(only static html) is loaded I send ajax request to my WebApi constroller that calls `GenericReposirory` `Get()` method that throw error: `The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.` 

Without this line of code everything works OK, but without setting it probably the context will not be dispose.

My `UnitOfWork` class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
   private readonly VotingSystemContext _context;
   private bool _disposed;

   //GenericRepository properties

   private void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
      if (!_disposed)
      {
         if (disposing)
         {
            _context.Dispose();
         }
      }
      _disposed = true;
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
}
```

P.S. I use the latest version of **Unity 3.5.1404**.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

**Get() method of Repository:**

```
public sealed class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public GenericRepository(VotingSystemContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    private readonly VotingSystemContext _context;

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "", int? page = null, int? pageSize = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        List<string> properties = includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        properties.ForEach(property =>
            {
                query = query.Include(property);
            });
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }
        if (page != null && pageSize != null)
        {
            query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);
        }
        return query;
    }
    // other methods like Delete, Update and GetById
    }
}
```

**ApiController's `Get()` method:**

```
public IEnumerable<VotingModel> Get(int page = 1, int size = 10)
{
    //get all themes
    List<Theme> themes = _themeService.GetAll(page, size);
    //convert themes to VotingModel (same model as Theme just without converting system throw an error about serializing object and also add new filed UserName).
    List<VotingModel> model = themes.Select(t =>
        {
            MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(t.UserId ?? -1);
            return t.ToVotingModel(membershipUser != null ? membershipUser.UserName : string.Empty);
        }).ToList();
    return model;
}
```

**Service `GetAll()` method:**

```
public List<Theme> GetAll(int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
{
    return UnitOfWork.ThemeRepository.Get(null, null, "Comments", page, pageSize).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Seeing your repository `Get()` code might help, along with your controller.

Comment: @bcr, hello, I added additional info.

Comment: I use this guy's soution: http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/12/Unity-IoC-lifetime-management-IDisposable-part1.aspx.

Comment: I don't see the constructor(s) for the `UnitOfWork` class. Does it have a `DbContext` injected into it? Also, does the service have a `UnitOfWork` injected into it? The chain seems a little wonky here without more info.

Comment: @bcr, for both questions answer is yes.

Comment: @KeithPayne For what it's worth, looks like his blog moved that link here: http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2013/02/12/Unity-IoC-lifetime-management-IDisposable-part1 (no `.aspx` any more, I guess) It links to [a description of different lifetime managers here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121215111751/https://ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/unity-build-in-lifetime-managers/).

Answer (score 5):

So I would have the dependency structure like so:

- UnitOfWork - gets DbContext
- Repository - gets UnitofWork
- Service - gets Repository(ies)
- ApiController - gets Service(s)

and you'd stick with Unity handling the lifetime of each. The thing is though, you'd want the Services to have request scope, just like the others (UoW and Repos). You may have the service lifetime set up that way, but I don't know Unity off the top of my head. I can see that you do have the UofW and repos set with request lifetimes.

The big difference being that the `UnitOfWork` doesn't have a dependency on repositories, but rather the other way around. So the repository base class gets its `DbSet<T>` via the `UnitOfWork` which has the `DbContext.` You'd have some method on `UnitOfWork` that would return an `IDbSet<T>` just as if you were calling that on the `DbContext.`The `UnitOfWork` being a wrapper for `DbContext` which in itself is pretty Unit of Work-like.

```
public sealed class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;
    private readonly IUoW _uoW;

    public GenericRepository(IUoW unitOfWork)
    {
        _uoW = unitOfWork;
        _dbSet = _uoW.Set<T>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "", int? page = null, int? pageSize = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;
        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }
        List<string> properties = includeProperties.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        properties.ForEach(property =>
            {
                query = query.Include(property);
            });
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            query = orderBy(query);
        }
        if (page != null && pageSize != null)
        {
            query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);
        }
        return query;
    }
// other methods like Delete, Update and GetById
}
```

The `UnitOfWork` would be similar, but take the `DbContext` as the dependency (you may already have this but omitted the constructor):

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
   private readonly VotingSystemContext _context;
   private bool _disposed;

   public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
   {
       _context = context;
   }

   public IDbSet<T> Set<T>()
   {
       return _context.Set<T>();
   ]
}
```

The service would have the repository injected:

```
public class ThemeService
{
    private IRepository<Theme> ThemeRepository { get; set; }

    public ThemeService(IRepository<Theme> themeRepo)
    {
        ThemeRepository = themeRepo;
    }

    public List<Theme> GetAll(int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        return ThemeRepository.Get(null, null, "Comments", page, pageSize).ToList();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

The `ApiController` would get the needed services injected, in this case the `ThemeService`:

```
public class ApiController ThemeController
{
    private ThemeService _themeService;

    public ThemeController(ThemeService service) // along with any other needed services
    {
        _themeService = service;
    }

    public IEnumerable<VotingModel> Get(int page = 1, int size = 10)
    {
        //get all themes
        List<Theme> themes = _themeService.GetAll(page, size);
        //convert themes to VotingModel (same model as Theme just without converting system throw an error about serializing object and also add new filed UserName).
        List<VotingModel> model = themes.Select(t =>
            {
                MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(t.UserId ?? -1);
                return t.ToVotingModel(membershipUser != null ? membershipUser.UserName : string.Empty);
            }).ToList();
        return model;
}
```

The ultimate idea being that the Unity container handles the lifetime of all the dependencies and the `UnitOfWork` doesn't have to try to manage repositories. Your line

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

would stay and the `DbContext` would get disposed by Unity, and you don't have to call `Dispose()` on it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the main reason I have UoW is that I want to have all repositories in one place because some of my Service classes use more than one repository and I want to pass only `IUnitOfWork` in constructor.

Comment: Yeah, as I said you could inject more than one repository into a service by adding them to the constructor arguments. But I think you might want to try taking the Dispose code out of your UnitOfWork and let the Unity container both inject the DbContext and manage its lifetime, to avoid the problem in your OP.

Comment: I tried to remove `IDisposable` with its `Dispose` method but the problem still persist.

Comment: I've +1'd this because it is a great example of how to structure an application. There is so much discrepancy out there on how to use UnitOfWork and Repository patterns. This is one of the first examples I've seen that makes a lot of structural sense. Nice.

Comment: Why dont you use DbContext interface (IDbContext) in unitofwork. So the unitofwork would be easy to test

Comment: Very nice, this is mostly how I built the reference architecture I use for new projects. It's worth noting that if you don't add the "RegisterModule" line in your Unity config class, Dispose will not get called. We ran into a scenario at work where this has caused several hanging connections left open, and a high ASYNC_NETWORK_IO count is SQL Server. That's our primary suspect, anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use Microsoft.Practices.Unity.HierarchicalLifetimeManager instead, that´s way:

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, VotingSystemContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
```

> The Microsoft.Practices.Unity.HierarchicalLifetimeManager provides:
>
> 1. A Dispose() call after each request
> 2. The same DbContext instance per request

Like article: https://jasenhk.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/unit-of-work-and-repository-pattern-with-unity-dependency-injection/

Comment: you should not reuse the DbContext per request