# Implementing UnitOfWork in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have basic *Web Api 2* app with layer of business logic and data layer. *UnitOfWork* incapsulates *DBContext*.

My UnitOfWok:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public KnowBaseDBContext context { get; set; } = new KnowBaseDBContext();

    public int Save()
    {
        var res = context.SaveChanges();

        return res;
    }

    public void AttachToContext<T>(T obj) where T : class
    {
        var dbset = context.Set<T>();

        dbset.Attach(obj);
    }
    // dispose()
}
```

I've also implemented *Dependency Injection* using *Unity Container* and my *config* of *Unity Container* for *UnitOfWork*:

```
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(),
                                                        new InjectionConstructor());
```

What I want to do is to call *UnitOfWork.Save()* in *ActionFilter.OnActionExecuted*:

```
public sealed class CommitOnSuccess : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {    
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
        {
            unitOfWork = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();

            unitOfWork.Save();
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

but from what I see *Unity Container* works in *context* of *Action*(don't know how does it work exactly) so I can't get appropriate *context* in *ActionFilter* and, therefore, can't save changes in my db. How do I *SaveChanges* in a right way?

How I use *UbitOfWork* (don't worry, will be opptimized):

```
private void UpdateSecondarySkills(Vacancy v, ICollection<int> skills)
{
    var old_secondary_skills = v.TechSkills;
    var ids = old_secondary_skills.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
    foreach (var skill in old_secondary_skills.ToList())
    {
        if (!skills.Contains(skill.Id))
        {
            v.TechSkills.Remove(skill);
        }
    }
    if (v != null)
    {
        foreach (var skill in skills)
        {
            if (!ids.Contains(skill))
            {
                var existing_skill = new TechSkill { Id = skill };
                unitOfWork.AttachToContext<TechSkill>(existing_skill);
                v.TechSkills.Add(existing_skill);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen the `UnitOfWork` pattern turn into a huge mess in a project I'm working on.  Personally I think you should open the context do your DB work and close it when you're done and that should all occur in your DAL layer.  It's best to limit DB interactions to the smallest scope possible.

Comment: do you need a unit of work in a webapi setting?  wouldn't the unit of work be the request?

Comment: @juharr Unfortunately my project is simply a wrapper on database with some smart stuff it can do, so this is not a solution for me

Comment: @Fran, how do I parse it as a parameter then?

Comment: Where does the `unitOfWork` field come from? that is the most important part. And are you sure the LifetimeManager is right? Also take a look at the following topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430377/unity-di-inject-dbcontext-with-perrequestlifetimemanager also edited my answer

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to commit changes in the filter. Often you need to return values which you have only after database operations finished. E.g. it's good practice to return *created at route* parameter with id of entity which was created

Comment: @Jordy van Eijk thank you so much! The problem was in wrong LifetimeManager.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Can u please tell me what is the best way to commit chages?

Comment: @Roman commit changes where you work with uow - if you are adding some operations in controller action, then commit it there. If you are using some (domain) service, then commit there

Answer (score 1):

Modify your global.asax

to add these event handlers

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest() { CurrentContext = new YourDbcontext; }

    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (CurrentContext != null)
            CurrentContext .Dispose();
    }
```

add this property to your global.asax

```
    private const string ContextKey = "current.session";

    public static YourDbContext CurrentContext
    {
        get { return (ISession) HttpContext.Current.Items[ContextKey]; }
        private set { HttpContext.Current.Items[ContextKey] = value; }
    }
```

Now you need to setup you container to call the CurrentContext property when resolving for your context.  I don't know how Unity does that.  I use Castle Windsor and you register it like this

```
        container
            .Register(Component.For<DbContext>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => MvcApplication.CurrentContext)
                .LifeStyle
                .PerWebRequest);
```

You might be able to do this

```
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<YourDbContext>()
            .BasedOn<DbContext>()
                .LifeStyle
                .PerWebRequest);
```

but i haven't tried that.

then as long as you are resolving your ApiControllers through your container, just pass the YouDbContext in the constructor.

Now you should have you context resolved per user per web request.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using the `UnitOfWork` anywhere inside your project where you do database things on the `DBContext`. If not the `UnitOfWork` has probably another `DBContext` so it does not see any changes so it will not save any

Maybe you need to take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430377/unity-di-inject-dbcontext-with-perrequestlifetimemanager)

Comment: I do. It has some methods which I use in services.

Comment: Can you update your question with Some code examples of your services so we can see how u ise it