# Unity PerRequestLifetimeManager throwing exception in Web API app in RegisterTypes() method

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container

I configured Unity in my Web API application to inject the dependencies, but it's throwing an exception when I try to register the DbContext with PerRequestLifetimeManager. ***It works fine if I use the default LifeTimeManager***. I have Unity.MVC and Unity.Webapi nuget packages added to the app. Here is the code for RegisterTypes.

```
container                
.AddNewExtension<Interception>()                
.RegisterType(typeof(DbContext), typeof(MyDbContext), "MyContext", new PerRequestLifetimeManager())                
.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Country>), typeof(Repository<Country>), new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve(typeof(DbContext),"MyContext")))                
.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Region>), typeof(Repository<Region>), new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve(typeof(DbContext), "MyContext")))
```

It throws the following exception in RegisterTypes when I run the app.

> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException...
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: The
>   PerRequestLifetimeManager can only be used in the context of an HTTP
>   request.Possible causes for this error are using the lifetime manager
>   on a non-ASP.NET application, or using it in a thread that is not
>   associated with the appropriate synchronization context.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32929021/6823285)

Comment: The answer suggests to use 'HierarchicalLifetimeManager' as it automatically disposes DbContext after each request. I don't think that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Just like the error message says, I was trying to inject the DbContext in a non Http Request context at the time of application initialization. It works fine if I do it as shown below, without trying to configure the "InjectionConstructor" inside RegisterType for Repositories. It successfully injects a new instance of DbContext in the repository every request. Seems like you can't use InjectionConstructor for Types that are registered with "PerRequestLifetimeManager".

```
 container                
.AddNewExtension<Interception>()                
.RegisterType(typeof(DbContext), typeof(MyDbContext), "MyContext", new PerRequestLifetimeManager())                
.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Country>), typeof(Repository<Country>))                
.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<Region>), typeof(Repository<Region>))
```